# Trying to install Horde with php8.0/php7.4

Tags: php, pear, horde

AlmaLinux 9, LAMP up-to-date.
Acouple of weeks ago I tried to install Horde webmail but I gave up after “install failed”.
That time I followed [pre requisites ++](https://www.horde.org/apps/webmail/docs/INSTALL#id2).
Now I am trying it again. I created a virtual server mail.domain.com
I simply followed [Quick Install](https://www.horde.org/apps/webmail/docs/INSTALL#id1).
I have installed php 8.0 from scratch and some days ago php 7.4.
For mail.domain.com I selected php 7.4
Running `pear install -a -B horde/horde` I get a very long list of warnings and requirements. It starts with

```
WARNING: “pear/Console_Getopt” is deprecated in favor of “pear/Console_GetoptPlus”
```

and other deprectations I don’t know how to update.
Continues a long list of modules that require lower versions of php.
For example:

```
horde/Horde_Core requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 8.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 8.0.0alpha1), installed version is 8.0.27
```

I don’t know how to tell Horde install to use php 7.4.
A lot of other are like

```
horde/Horde_Log requires package “horde/Horde_Exception” (version >= 2.0.0, version <= 3.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 3.0.0alpha1)
```

And finally

```
pecl/mongo requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 5.99.99), installed version is 8.0.27
horde/Horde_Thrift requires PHP (version >= 5.3.0, version <= 8.0.0alpha1, excluded versions: 8.0.0alpha1), installed version is 8.0.27
No valid packages found
install failed
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can ignore deprecation warning, it's up to the developers of the software to fix them, not you.
2. *I don’t know how to tell Horde install to use php 7.4*
   Just install one version of PHP, the one that is required. Preferably through the package system, not by compiling it yourself. You don't want to recompile it again and again for every security issue found and fixed.
3. PHP5? seriously? It has been [end of life for years](https://www.php.net/eol.php) (7.4 is also end of life btw). If this is required you are trying to install software from the stone age (of the internet). Don't use it. Most likeley you just used versions from a horribly outdated installation guide, look if you find current versions from that software instead that is built to work with newer versions of PHP.

Comment: Side note: Horde Webmail [has not been updated since 2019](https://github.com/horde/webmail/). Seems pretty dead. I would look for alternatives.

Comment: Yes, I give up with Horde. php8.0 was installed by default server installation. I had to also install php7.4 as a a couple of user requirements. Thanks!